# Failing hstore tests Django

Tags: django, unit-testing, hstore

I am having a problem when I get the value from a hstore field. The situation is something like this:

model:

```
class Model(models.Model):
    hstoreField = HStoreField()
```

test cases:

```
def test_case_1(self):
        new_model = Model.objects.create(
            hstoreField = {
                'key1': 'value1',
                'key2': 'value2'
            }
        )

        self.assertEqual(new_model.subscription['key1'], 'value1')
        self.assertEqual(new_model.subscription['key2'], 'value2')

def test_case_2(self):
        Model.objects.create(
            hstoreField = {
                'key1': 'value1',
                'key2': 'value2'
            }
        )

        new_model = Model.objects.get( id = 1 ) // assume it works 

        self.assertEqual(new_model.hstoreField['key1'], 'value1')
        self.assertEqual(new_model.hstoreField['key2'], 'value2')
```

When I run those test cases, the first one passes, but the second one fails and the error thrown is: `TypeError: string indices must be integers`. Checking the value of hstoreField is a string and it should be a dict.

The error only happens in tests, in real code both cases work. Can you help me guys?